# How to apply blank web part page layout to default page in onet.xml for a site template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to use the blank web part page in all the new pages and in the default home page when a site is created.

This is what I have so far

```
<WebFeatures>
        <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing -->
        <Feature ID="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" >
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx" />
          </Properties>
        </Feature>



<Modules>
    <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True" Type="Ghostable" >
        <Property Key="PublishingPageLayout" value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page" />
```

But I got this exception

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPSiteAdministration siteAdministration, String strWebTemplate, String strRedirect, Boolean bCreateDefaultGroups, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) Attempting to delete the site collection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to deploy a page in the publishing "Pages" library whith the BlankWebPartPage page layout :

```
<Module Name="Pages" Url="Pages" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files\Pages" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <File Url="Home.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="Home.aspx">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Welcome" />
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Welcome Page" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~siteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page" />
    </File>
</Module>
```

Comment: Interesting. This does require adding some sort of aspx file to the solution, though, right? (The reference to Home.aspx.) Would be nice to just have Elements.xml and nothing else in order to make a publishing or site page.